# Google AdUnit hiding

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, adsense

Has anyone figured how to manipulate the `AdUnit` element from google?
E.g. hiding, etc.?

So far I can change opacity and move it vertically, but only before the ads load.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I see the connection to google maps, could you clarify please?

Comment: You can display the google adsense ads on your google mapsusing AdUnit API and I wanted to be able to hide it ... but I found the solution myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found solution myself:

```
var t=setTimeout("closeAdd()",2000);});

function closeAdd(){
 $('#add').append('<span id="close_but">Close</span>');
 $('#close_but').css('position','absolute');
 $('#close_but').css('color','blue');
 $('#close_but').css('top','0px');
 $('#close_but').css('left','425px');
 $('#close_but').click(function(){
  $('#add').hide();});
 }
```

Using jQuery I am adding the 'Close' span to the node containing the add. The actual placing depends on the format of the add unit, here I have "AdFormat.BANNER". Anyway, I also attach the click handler to the Close span which hides the add containing element.

BTW. delaying the manipulation is necessarry as google does strange manipulations with a node and untill the adds load completely.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `setPosition(null)` on the `AdUnit` will remove it from the map.  See http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#AdUnit

Comment: setPosition(null) does not work: 'Invalid value for property <position>: null' is shown by Error Console

Comment: Well, that's certainly disappointing, as the documentation explicitly says that it should remove the AdUnit from the map.  I wonder if `setMap(null)` would work.

Comment: `setMap(null)` actually works but I prefer the jQuery way as I can play with the effects. Thanks anyway.